# SQL filtering on range of dates

Tags: sql

I have couple of tables. The base table is 'JOB REquisition'. The table has columns 'JobCode' and 'Open Date' column as showin in the screenshot.
Now I need to join this table with the 'JOBCODE' table which basically gets updated on a regular basis. SCreenshot Attached. I need to join both tables and based on the 'Open DAte' column in the base table I need to select the appropriate record from the JobCode table. Example - Open DAte '2018-09-12' should be mapped to the second record in the 'JobCode' table as the effective date for the second record is '2017-01-01. What will be the query to achieve the above? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAI5Z.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KmDj.png)

Comment: You will need a SQL JOIN (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to link the tables along with WHERE clause (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) to accomplish this. There are many samples and tutorials on basic syntax.

Comment: Use `ON` to "link" tables together. It's called a `JOIN`. w3f**ls...

Comment: I understand that but how do I pick the exact record from the 'JOBCODE' table?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Make it easy to assist you! ([mcve].)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your questions with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)